# Fixing scene in Qgis2threejs plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

How to fix the scene/view in QGIS within the Qgis2threejs plugin, in a way that I can use the same scene for different areas?

Wireframe in camera view is fixing scene but only on particular area/coordinates.